# How can I append to my KeyValuePair?

Tags: c#

My `list` returns back `<string, string>` apparently. How can I append the second string in my KeyValuePair and add in the ID that I get back from my second database call?

```
    // Database calls here

    KeyValuePair<string, string> parks = new KeyValuePair<string, string>();

    DataSet dset = new DataSet();

    var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Select one", "0"));
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        //My database calls including:
         db.AddInParameter(comm, "@pID", DBType.Int32, row[1]);
         dset = db.ExecuteDataSet(comm);
         string attr = dset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Value"].ToString();
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(row[0].ToString() + " - " + attr, row[1].ToString()));

    }

    return list;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` key and value are readonly. you can use `Dictionary<string,string>` for you work and get `KeyValuePair<string, string>` from it.

I think this works:

```
// Database calls here
Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();

list.Add("Select one", "0");
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{

    list.Add(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString());

}

//Another database call that gets back an ID. I want to add/append this ID into my second string in my KeyValue Pair.

return list;
```

for append the second string you can use `list["/*Your ID*/"]= YourData;`

**`List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` is not good way. It's like that you use a cup of tea for offing the fire!**

Comment: @TCC: Dictionary Is the solution of the problems like yours.

Comment: I kept it as a KeyValuePair. I have edited my code above to show you what I have done.

Answer (score 3):

`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is immutable. If you want to stick with using `KeyValuePair<string, string>`, you have to remove the pair that you want to modify, and add a new pair with the modified values.

Alternatively, use a different data type. If you are going to be modifying values, use a type that allows you to modify values.

Comment: Any example on how to remove and then implement that with my code?